# How to seperate matching lines in a file using shell script

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a xml file something like :

```
<Channel Mode="None"  compressed="false" internal="true"
                          listening="false"        name="Specsavers_Visma_Write_File_Channel">
            <ExchangeProtocolRef name="Generic-File"/>
            <TransportProtocolRef name="File">
               <ParameterValue name="polling_interval"  value="5"/>
             </DeliveryChannel>

         <Channel Mode="None"  compressed="false" internal="true"
                          listening="true"        name="Local_JMS_ListeningChannel"       >
            <ExchangeProtocolRef name="Generic-JMS"/>
            <TransportProtocolRef name="JMS">
               <ParameterValue name="polling_interval"  value="5"/>               
         </Channel>
```

and many more repeating lines like above.

I want to write a shell script/Unix command which process the above XML file and display the attribute value of "name" for the "Channel" tags having `listening="true"`

I worked some commands like :

```
 grep  'Channel' tp_selfservice_seb.xml | grep -b -o  name
    grep  'Channel' tp_selfservice_seb.xml | grep 'name*
```

they are just displaying name but not attribute value.

Comment: You want to do this with `grep`? I believe XML is better dealt with XML-aware tools. And there's never a lack of such tools.

Comment: That snippet isn't even proper XML, I think. In line 4, it opens a `TransportProtocolRef` but in line 6, it closes a `DeliveryChannel`

Comment: So, first, check for `<Channel ... >`, then inside that, check for `listening="true"`, if that is found, return the string after `name=`. Is that correct so far?

Comment: actually, i have to do this as a part of an shell script. so, i am thinking a solution in shell scripting.

Comment: @chw21 yes.. u are right but how can we workout that through shell scriptiing commands